# Can't get OpenScad $Special variables to work "Correctly"

Tags: openscad

I'd like to create some functions in a library whose behavior I want the option to modify using $Precision similar to how $fn controls the number of facets in many built-in objects and operations.

For example if I use the cylinder object or the linear_extrude operation I need not specify $fn, $fa or $fs anywhere in my object file.  The library has defaults and no warning or error occurs.  However if I DO specify '$fn=45;' at the beginning of my object file then all objects or operations that make use of the variable will use this value rather than the default unless I override in a lower scope or explicitly with a parameter.

The problem seems to be that this isn't possible for USER libraries.

If I DON'T declare the variable $Precision (and assign a value) in my library then any use of the library throws a warning on EVERY library call unless I specify a value in my object file.

If I DO specify a value in my library then there doesn't seem to be any way of overriding the value other than by explicitly listing one as a  parameter in every function call.  That kind of defeats the purpose.  Specifying a value at any other scope in my object file DOES NOT override any default set in my library.  This seems to be true no matter where in the library I set the default and no matter where in my object file I put the "use" or "override assignment" statement.

As an example, I want a function like this in a library.

```
function fn(r=0) = ((r<=0?1:r*2)*3.1415926)/($Precision==undef?0.5:($Precision<0.1 ? 0.5 : $Precision));
```

When I use it I don't want to be required to specify $Precision=... to avoid

```
WARNING: Ignoring unknown variable '$Precision', in file...
```

But if I do declare $Precision in my object file I want it used in all ways similar to how $fn is seen by the objects and operations that interrogate it.

Comment: Use is_undef($Precision) instead for checking if the variable is set.

Comment: Deserves to be an answer rather than just a comment.  The doc I've got doesn't mention the is_... functions - which I now know about thanks to you.  Works perfectly.

Comment: Always good to have http://openscad.org/cheatsheet/ around :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `$Precision == undef` will still always cause the warning with newer versions of OpenSCAD.

For this specific check [`is_undef`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Type_Test_Functions#is_undef) was introduced, making it possible to check a variable without producing a warning.